# Dynamic Meta Tags For Social Sharing Angular 6+ Universal

Tags: angular, client-side, meta-tags, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I guess this question has been asked too many times because I have gone through almost every possible question that deals with this.

**My Need Simplified:** I would like to create social share buttons  for my website that uses Angular 7 and has universal properly setup.

**Detail:** I am looking for a solution that allows me to dynamically update Meta Tags for Facebook, Twitter and other social media platforms in such a way that when I click the share button I should share content that is specific to the current article in view. **Important:** The data for these meta tags is obtained by making an API call thus the **solution cannot include hard-coded data.**

**Tried Solution:** I tried the solution of using Meta from '@angular/platform-browser' but the result is that it updates the tags after the DOM has already been rendered.

My component's ngOnInit has the following:

```
this.musicService.getTrackInfo(track._id)
                .subscribe(track => {  
            this.metaService.setTag('og:title', track.name);
            this.metaService.setTag('og:type', 'music.song'); });
```

**Research Made:**

- https://samvloeberghs.be/posts/better-sharing-on-social-media-platforms-with-angular-universal

**Similar Unresolved Issues:**

- [Angular universal Server Side Rendering, Meta tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169175/angular-universal-server-side-rendering-meta-tags)
- [angular universal update meta tags with dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53406926/2497008)
- [Updating meta tags for SEO using angular universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437166/updating-meta-tags-for-seo-using-angular-universal)
- [Dynamic update meta tags with facebook share - angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53883020/dynamic-update-meta-tags-with-facebook-share-angular-6)

Could someone please provide a full, step by step solution for this issue and also explanations to why the current way of using Meta is not working.

Comment: Did you look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842315/angular2-seo-how-to-manipulate-the-meta-description#comment81636282_43537554

Comment: The solution provided here is like most solutions. If you inspect, the tags are updated, but is you view source, they are not updated and hence crawlers are not seeing the tags

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem with your universal setup, because you can change meta data with SSR. Give it a try with a new project.

Comment: I will try with a new project. But how can I have a problem with my SSR when the DOM is rendering okay?

Comment: Maybe your async requests are not finishing properly on the server-side. You said that you make API requests before the update. I think that's the issue.

Comment: Does `setTag` really exist? What if you use `.updateTag({name: 'og:title', content: track.name})`. And also make sure that you have no error in the terminal console where you run your nodejs universal server from

Comment: I actually I mearnt addTag().. setTag is for ngx-meta.. And I tried both and they do not work.

Answer (score 0):

It does work for me using updateTag.
In index.html I've added all tags without value i.e.

```
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="">
```

Also I'm adding the dynamic values like this:

```
this.meta.updateTag({
        name: 'twitter:description', content: *value from api*
      });
```

Comment: If your angular version > 5 try using angular ssr

Comment: is it work in angular 8 with out angular SSR ?